# No buttons/labels/anything will re-appear after I set alpha back to 1.0

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, fadein, fadeout

What I want: After the Viewcontroller is called, I want to fade in all my elements in this Viewcontroller, except for the background. The background must stay.

What goes wrong: As you see in my code, for something to fade in, it first needs to be removed. The remove part is doing great. But, when I want it to re-appear, nothing happens. When I use the print function to see the alpha of a random label, it is set to 1.0. I can not figure out what I am doing wrong.

This is my code:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    Removeeverything()
    Fadein()
}

func Removeeverything() {
    for view in self.view.subviews as [UIView] {
        if let btn = view as? UIButton {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.0, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {

                btn.alpha = 0.0

                }, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    for view in self.view.subviews as [UIView] {
        if let btn = view as? UILabel {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.0, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {

                btn.alpha = 0.0

                }, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    for view in self.view.subviews as [UIView] {
        if let btn = view as? UIImageView {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.0, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {

                btn.alpha = 0.0

                }, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}

func Fadein() {
    Backgrond.alpha = 1.0
    for view in self.view.subviews as [UIView] {
        if let btn = view as? UIButton {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn, animations: {

                btn.alpha = 1.0

                }, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    for view in self.view.subviews as [UIView] {
        if let btn = view as? UILabel {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn, animations: {

                btn.alpha = 1.0

                }, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    for view in self.view.subviews as [UIView] {
        if let btn = view as? UIImageView {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.7, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn, animations: {

                btn.alpha = 1.0

                }, completion: nil)
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say that the problem is that `UIView.animateWithDuration` is executed asynchronous (that is - your `fadeIn()` function will execute before the animations in `removeEverything()` are complete).

Simply remove the `UIView.animateWithDuration` operations from your `Removeeverything()`. Since you've set the duration argument to 0.0 nothing will really change (except that the code should now work)

```
func removeEverything() {
    for v in view.subviews.filter({ $0 is UIButton || $0 is UILabel || $0 is UIImageView }) {
        v.alpha = 0
    }
}

func fadeIn() {
    // Background.alpha = 1.0
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0, options: .CurveEaseIn, animations: {
        for v in view.subviews.filter({ $0 is UIButton || $0 is UILabel }) {
            v.alpha = 1
        }
    }, completion: nil)
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.7, delay: 0, options: .CurveEaseIn, animations: {
        for v in view.subviews.filter({ $0 is UIImageView }) {
            v.alpha = 1
        }
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

That code snippet should work as expected. I used the `filter` function on the array and got rid of a couple of unnecessary casts to make the code more readable. Hope it helps!

Comment: This surely helps to clean up the code, thank you! Except, it will just fade out, after the seconds are up. (Where the seconds are now 1.0 and 0.7.) I tested it out with 10 seconds. It will fade in, and automatically fade out within 10 seconds. Are we using the wrong Animation?

Comment: It works now, I think some images were not working... thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, have you tried setting the alpha to something unrecognizably low like `0.01` rather than removing them entirely? You could also try matching the color of the button to the background and then fading it back in that way.

You may also need to call `self.background.alpha` or `view.background.alpha`

Also, you should really camel-case your function names.